# AC voltage measurement using microcontroller

Tags: ac

I am using this below circuit to measure AC voltage using a pic microcontroller
PIC32MX330F064H.
[image]

Here in this circuit resisitor R1 and R2 form a voltage divider to attenuate the AC Line voltage. Resisitor R3 and R4 acts a level shitfer so that the AC signal zero level is shifted to mid voltage level of the DC 3.3V. This prevents negative voltage developing at analog pin of the microcontroller. Resisitor R5 acts a current limiting resistor.

Now my question is wheter this circuit will load the analog pin of the microcontroller? If it loads than how to prevent it. Secondly do i have to add some components like diode for safety of the microcontroller.

What will the voltage developed at analog pin if Neutral is not connected or gets disconnected during measurement? 
It is possible to detect Open Neutral using the same circuit?

Comment: Please don't do this it is very unsafe. You need isolation - how you do it depends on what you want to measure

Comment: If you tell us more about your system, in particular what sort of mains power supply you have, we may be able to suggest a better and safer way measuring mains voltage.

Comment: that won't work unless `GND` is connected ONLY to `NEUTRAL` amd if it is you'll need to isolate the microcontroller.

Comment: Notice that when the connection to neutral breaks, you have line voltage all over the place!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not going to work well (if at all) and is not safe. From your questions, it is evident that you should not be playing with line voltage.

First off, in an ideal case (where line and neutral are entirely isolated from 3.3V and GND), there is only a single connection. Kirchoff's Laws say no current will flow (no loop) and therefore the voltage at the analog input will be a *constant* ~3.3V/2 (a little bit lower, due to the impedance of the input pin).

However, if there is a little current leakage between the AC line and your 3.3V and GND, you've got trouble. For instance, if you have a mere 200uA leakage between neutral and GND, the analog input will swing between ~5V and -2V. Your voltage shifter does not prevent negative voltage. You need to capacitively couple when trying to add DC offsets.

I don't know what you mean by "load the analog pin". The pin isn't outputting a voltage: it doesn't get loaded, *it does the loading*. You can check the datasheet to find the impedance of an analog input.

**TL;DR: Don't do this. Not only is it entirely unisolated, it doesn't at all do what you think it does.**

Comment: I'm thinking of using a similar setup, with biasing  and voltage follower amplifier for ac sensing. I'm adding a TVS and a zener to protect the microcontroller. And the whole setup is temporary till I get my hands on an isolation amplifier. So, what else should I be concerned about in the mean time, if I want to get things going rightaway?